Existence of $f(X)$ such that $E[f(X)|Y]=g(Y)$
$X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables that take full support on $[0,1]$. Their joint PDF $p(x,y)$ is strictly log-supermodular, that is, $\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x',y)}$ for $x>x'$ strictly increases with $y$.
Given a non-decreasing function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, how do I know if there exists a non-decreasing function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$E[f(X)|Y]=g(Y)? \tag{1}$$
If you don't have an answer, I would also appreciate some guidance on which area of math I should look up to solve this problem. I'm guessing I will need some algebra - which branch should I look at?

My attempt: I thought about an analogy with discrete random variables:
$X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables and take values in $\{1,...,n\}$. The probability of $X=i$ conditional on $Y=j$, $p_{ij}$, is strictly log-supermodular in $(i,j)$, that is, $\frac{p_{i,j}}{p_{i',j}}$ for $i>i'$ strictly increases with $j$.
Then (1) becomes
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n f_i p_{ij} = g_j.\tag{2}
$$
Let
$$
P=
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{1,1} & \cdots & p_{1,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_{n,1} & \cdots & p_{n,n} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then (2) holds for all $j$ is equivalent to
$$
(f_1,\cdots,f_n)
P=
\begin{pmatrix}
g_1 \\
\vdots \\
g_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{3}
$$
If $P$ is full rank, then there is $(f_1,\cdots,f_n)$ such that (3) holds.
But I even get stuck here. First, I don't know if log-supermodularity of $p_{i,j}$ implies $P$ is full rank. Second, I don't know if log-supermodularity of $p_{i,j}$ implies when $(f_1,\cdots,f_n)$ exists, there is one that is non-decreasing.
And then I don't know how to go back to the original continuous case. There (3) changes from $n$ equations in $n$ variables to uncountably many equations in uncountably many variables.
As you can tell, my knowledge about linear algebra is very limited. I hope to learn more math so that I can understand this problem. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Given $Y$, the answer is the constant function $f(X)=g(Y)$.

@Amir Sorry, I should have been clearer: I'm looking for $f$ such that $E[f(X)|Y]=g(Y)$ for all $Y\in[0,1]$.
